# Passing closures dynamically to .filter(..) results in compiler error

Tags: rust, closures

I'm working on the I/O project of the book (basically a grep replica).
The function takes a `insensitive` parameter, which should make the text-search case-insensitive.

If that parameter is `true`, the only thing that will change in the function body is the filtering I'm doing on the lines, so I'd like to conditionally change the callback.

```
fn search_lines<'a>(query: &str, content: &'a str, insensitive: bool) -> Vec<&'a str> {
  let lines = content.lines();
  
  let mut matches = Vec::<&str>::new();
  
  let mut condition = |line: &str| -> bool { line.contains(query) };

  if insensitive {
    condition = |line: &str| -> bool { 
      line.to_lowercase().contains(query.to_lowercase()) // err 1
    };
  };

  lines
    .filter::<dyn Fn(&str) -> bool>(condition) // err 2
    .for_each(|line| matches.push(line));

  matches
}
```

I am getting two compiler errors:

1. No two closures, even if identical, have the same type.
2. The `filter` method cannot be invoked on a Trait object.

I understand that two closures can't have the same type, they can just implement a specific function trait. But shouldn't I be able to specify such a trait for `filter`? Is there a way to change the callbacks conditionally?

Comment: Error 2: `dyn Fn(&str) -> bool` is a Dynamically Sized Type (DST). You try to give a DST as a type for your `filter` generic parameter `P`, but `P` is implicitly `Sized` [(see docs)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sized.html) and your DST is not.

Comment: You can use `insensitive` within your closure e.g 
`
 let condition = |line: &str| if insensitive { 
            line.contains(&query) 
    } else {
            line.to_lowercase().contains(&query.to_lowercase())
    }; ` so that you can avoid `Box`ing

Answer (score 0):

The first point `let mut condition = ...` is not very good because the compiler infer the size of closure and could not be compatible when you want change it.

One solution is:

```
let condition: Box<dyn Fn(&str) -> bool> = if insensitive {
    Box::new(|line: &str| -> bool { line.contains(&query) })
}else{
    Box::new(|line: &str| -> bool { line.to_lowercase().contains(&query.to_lowercase()) })
};
```

The next point is the filter. The signature is below

```
fn filter<P>(self, predicate: P) -> Filter<Self, P>
where
    P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool,
```

You sould use like this

```
fn search_lines<'a>(query: &str, content: &'a str, insensitive: bool) -> Vec<&'a str> {
  let lines = content.lines();
  
  let mut matches = Vec::<&str>::new();
  
  let condition: Box<dyn Fn(&str) -> bool> = if insensitive {
    Box::new(|line: &str| -> bool { line.contains(&query) })
  }else{
    Box::new(|line: &str| -> bool { line.to_lowercase().contains(&query.to_lowercase()) })
  };
  
  lines
   .filter(|x| condition(x)) // err 2
   .for_each(|line| matches.push(line));
    
  matches
}

fn main()
{
  println!("{:?}", search_lines("test1", "test1\ntest2", true));
}
```

Comment: The second point is incorrect. `filter()` accepts `Box<dyn Fn>`, because it also impls `FnMut`

Answer (score 0):

Your example has multiple errors, let's walk over them one by one.

First, you cannot store `dyn Trait` on stack, because it can have a variable size. `filter()` requires its callback to be `Sized`, and thus you cannot specify `dyn Trait`.

We can fix that by using `Box<dyn Fn(&str) -> bool>`:

```rust
pub fn search_lines<'a>(query: &str, content: &'a str, insensitive: bool) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let lines = content.lines();

    let mut matches = Vec::<&str>::new();

    let mut condition: Box<dyn Fn(&str) -> bool> =
        Box::new(|line: &str| -> bool { line.contains(query) });

    if insensitive {
        condition =
            Box::new(|line: &str| -> bool { line.to_lowercase().contains(&query.to_lowercase()) });
    };

    lines.filter(condition).for_each(|line| matches.push(line));

    matches
}
```

Then we get another two errors, the important is the following:

```rust
error[E0277]: expected a `FnMut<(&&str,)>` closure, found `dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r str) -> bool`
  --> src/lib.rs:14:18
   |
14 |     lines.filter(condition).for_each(|line| matches.push(line));
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^ expected an `FnMut<(&&str,)>` closure, found `dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r str) -> bool`
   |
   = help: the trait `FnMut<(&&str,)>` is not implemented for `dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r str) -> bool`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `for<'r> FnMut<(&'r &str,)>` for `Box<dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r str) -> bool>`
```

What happens?

If we'll look [at `filter()`'s signature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter), we'll see that it requires callback of type `P` `where P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool`. The important part is that filter doesn't give the callback an owned `Self::Item`, but a reference to it, `&Self::Item` since we need to use it after. `Self::Item` here is `&str`, so `&Self::Item` is `&&str`:

```rust
pub fn search_lines<'a>(query: &str, content: &'a str, insensitive: bool) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let lines = content.lines();

    let mut matches = Vec::<&str>::new();

    let mut condition: Box<dyn Fn(&&str) -> bool> =
        Box::new(|line: &&str| -> bool { line.contains(query) });

    if insensitive {
        condition =
            Box::new(|line: &&str| -> bool { line.to_lowercase().contains(&query.to_lowercase()) });
    };

    lines.filter(condition).for_each(|line| matches.push(line));

    matches
}
```

This works, but we can improve it a bit more.

First, `for_each(|line| matches.push(line))` is definitely not idiomatic. What you want is `collect()`:

```rust
pub fn search_lines<'a>(query: &str, content: &'a str, insensitive: bool) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let lines = content.lines();

    let mut condition: Box<dyn Fn(&&str) -> bool> =
        Box::new(|line: &&str| -> bool { line.contains(query) });

    if insensitive {
        condition =
            Box::new(|line: &&str| -> bool { line.to_lowercase().contains(&query.to_lowercase()) });
    };

    lines.filter(condition).collect()
}
```

Second, there is a small trick we can use to avoid the heap allocation of `Box`:

```rust
pub fn search_lines<'a>(query: &str, content: &'a str, insensitive: bool) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let lines = content.lines();

    let condition_intensive;
    let mut condition: &dyn Fn(&&str) -> bool = &|line: &&str| -> bool { line.contains(query) };

    if insensitive {
        condition_intensive =
            |line: &&str| -> bool { line.to_lowercase().contains(&query.to_lowercase()) };
        condition = &condition_intensive;
    };

    lines.filter(condition).collect()
}
```

Instead of storing the callback on the heap, we store it on the stack, *conditionally*.